# Dot product and linear combination of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I am currently going through the SVD intuition provided [here](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/12/10/svd/). In the section "From intuition to definition", It says that,

> First, note that any vector $\textbf{x}$ can be described using the
> basis vectors $\textbf{v1}$​ and $\textbf{v2}$ ​ in the following way,
>
> $$\textbf{x} = (\textbf{x}.\textbf{v1})\textbf{v1} + (\textbf{x}.\textbf{v2})\textbf{v2}$$

I am unable to understand the significance of the dot product here. Why are we projecting $\textbf{x}$ onto $\textbf{v1}$ and $\textbf{v2}$ to obtain the scalars for $\textbf{v1}$ and $\textbf{v2}$ that will result in $x$?

Comment: It is critical to note that the vectors $\mathbf v_i$ are *orthonormal.*  Using this, you can instantly obtain this equality by writing $\mathbf x=\alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1 + \alpha_2\mathbf{v}_2$ and computing those two dot products: they produce the $\alpha_i$ *because of the orthonormal relations.*  For such general questions about linear algebra, though, consider posting at [math.se].

Comment: Thank you @whuber!